# sqlalchemy python +select statement giving null value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

me is writing a simple code in python which should give me all the data available in my oracle table. Connection stuff are fine.

```
select column1,column2,column3 from table1.
```

column as following values

[image]

This is a huge table and 24 million rows. Issue is this is giving my null value in multiple columns, though it TEMPhas values. I thought The issue wat me feel is initial rows of these columns TEMPhas smaller (2 digit only) and dat's why anything having bigger than 2 digits get ignored by python. How can me write a select statement and take everything from oracle table irrespective of if the initial few hundred columns are null also.

But as suggested here this is not the reason, not sure why this is happening. Any help will be appriciated.

me is using python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is going to be anything to do with the data in the initial rows.

You can try selecting the last rows instead to see if this is the case:

```
SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT column1,column2,column3
          FROM table1
         ORDER BY column1 DESC
        )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

Comment: yes, it is not working,Not sure why this is happen, can you put some light on it.Or Do i have any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This was a space issue only but not in python. The table I was using in oracle was taking all the data but when I try to extract in python data frame it was null.I went in to oracle table and increase the size of columns, just to let you know oracle was showing this data before also but increasing the size helped python to consume this data.